# openDoc javascript in pdf portfolio

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, javascript-objects

I have a portfolio of forms I have created to use along with other counselors in my school district to simplify filling out what has become a huge program and part of our job...a very time consuming one I might add too.  I created this to save time with what has become what we do as school counselors (paperwork) with the goal to allow more time to do what we as counselors actually went to school to do, want to do, and love to do...spend time counseling and helping our students.  Last year I converted our district forms to fillable pdf files and then had some help developing the portfolio and the scripts that help it operate the way we needed it to.  I have learned a lot about pdf, pdf forms, and javascript but now I am running into trouble on a part we want to add.

Within the portfolio I have several forms.  Several of the forms have the same form fields.  So I have one pdf document (the main information form) that has a javascript to copy data entered into all forms that have the same form fields.  This prevents us from having to enter in the same info over and over (student name, ID, etc. etc,).
Then within certain forms I have a very similar script for users to click a button and copy data from that one form over to the Spanish form (this is great because we fill out the English form and can copy all that data entered over to the Spanish form with the click of a button for Spanish speaking/reading parents).

**EXAMPLE OF WHAT I HAVE (btw which works beautifully!!!)...**
A pdf doc titled "Meeting Forms."  This form has the following document level javascript.

```
// the list of files to process:
var lPortfolioFiles = [ "(I) Meeting Forms (Spanish).pdf" ];
function CopyDataToFile(source, dest){
// iterate over all form fields in the destination form and copy from
// the field with the same name from the source (if available)
for (var i=0; i<dest.numFields; i++) {
var fieldName = dest.getNthFieldName(i);
var f1 = source.getField(fieldName);
if (f1 != null) { 
dest.getField(fieldName).value = f1.value;
console.println("Field name: " +fieldName + "\nData = " + f1.value);
}
}
} 
function CopyData(doc) {
// what is our file name? var myFileName = doc.path;
// get the portfolio part of the path 
var re = /(\|.*\|)(U:(\uFEFF|\uFFFE)<0>)(.*)/; 
var res = myFileName.match(re); 
console.println(res[3]);
// process all files in the list for (var i in lPortfolioFiles) { 
var fileName = res[1] + res[2] + lPortfolioFiles[i]; 
var d2 = app.openDoc(fileName); 
CopyDataToFile(doc, d2);
}
}
```

**On the form I have a "Copy to Spanish" button with the following javascript**
`CopyData(this);`
**and the Spanish Form has the following document level javascript**
`this.disclosed = true;`

**WANT I NEED NOW AND CANNOT FIGURE OUT...**
I want to add another button/script to this same form that operates almost the same way.  I want the additional button to open another form within the portfolio.  So, I want it to operate exactly the same but just open the form for use not copy data into it.  I thought this would be simply modifying and using the above script but after countless hours and frustration I seem to only be stuck in the same place...nowhere.  Just when I thought I had learned so much Javascript. Ughhh.
I want to avoid using the "linking" method because after trying that users complained about continuously accidentally exiting out of the portfolio instead of the individual document (the linking method seems to open the linked forms differently).
Any help/example scripts to make this happen would be GREATLY APPRECIATED

Comment: What happens when you comment out the last line in the CopyData() function (do not run CopyDataToFile() )? Also, is the other document disclosed? (has the same document-level script as the Spanish Form)

Comment: Yes, the other document is disclosed.  What I tried was using the exact same script renaming it as OpenDoc (instead of CopyData) then changing the  var lPortfolioFiles = [ "(I) Meeting Forms (Spanish).pdf" ]; to the page I want that button to open var lPortfolioFiles = [ "(E) Additional Notes Pages2.pdf" ];  and changing that button's javascript to OpenDoc(this);.  I was surprised and confused as to why that wouldn't work but it didn't.  It made both buttons not function.